# Marionette ItemView and radio Buttons

Tags: backbone.js, radio-button, marionette

I have data being returned from a server with a status flag.  And on each ItemView I have some radio Buttons as follows:

```
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' value='0'></td> 
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' value='2'></td> 
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' value='1'></td>
```

As each ItemView is being created I want to check if the status returned by the server is the same value as the input value ie either 0,1, or 2 and if it is set that element to selected.

```
Recipe = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   ui: {
     comm: 'input[type=radio]'
},

onBeforeRender: function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.ui.comm.length; i++) {
        if(parseInt(this.ui.comm[i].value, 10) === this.model.get('status')) {
          this.ui.comm[i].$el.prop('selected')
        }
      }
    }
```

However, when I view the interface none of the radio buttons have a check in them.

When I debug the code I can see that the line `this.ui.comm[i].$el.prop('selected)` is being executed so I'm wondering why doesn't it display set the element to selected?  BTW I tried using that function on the onRender event also but the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with your approach, instead of having a `onBeforeRender` function whose whole function is to check the "state" and set it to checked. I would move that "logic" to the template and not have it handled in the view.

Your template would look something like:

```
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' <% if (status == '0') { %>checked='checked'<% } %>value='0'></td> 
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' <% if (status == '2') { %>checked='checked'<% } %>value='2'></td> 
<td><input type='radio' name='<%- id %>-typeRecipe' <% if (status == '1') { %>checked='checked'<% } %>value='1'></td>
```

and finally your render'er?? lol. would just look something like:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

---

This again is "my opinion" and you can handle it as you see fit, but i like it because that sort of mundane logic clutters the views and just leaves the person behind you reading more code than he/she has too. And ... i think this approach is more "elegant" because that loop you have going on can be avoided completely.

Comment: Cheers - I had started to out using your approach but became unstuck with the syntax.  thanks for setting me on the right path again.  Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

It is the `checked` property for radio inputs, not `selected`. Also you will want to set the second argument to `true`, to actually set value for that property, or you're just getting it otherwise.

```js
$('input.selectMe').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='typeRecipe' value='0'>
<input type='radio' name='typeRecipe' value='2' class="selectMe">
<input type='radio' name='typeRecipe' value='1'>
```